# How to span C# namespaces over multiple assemblies?

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, exe

A one-liner question does not make sense, so let me detail my challenge:

I have created 3 DLLs (**MyUtils, MyConnector, MyAgent**), each containing its own set of "internal" classes, types and members. All the classes, types and members are is their respective default namespace (same as their assembly name).

1. MyAgent needs to add reference to MyConnector and use some of its classes. MyConnector needs to add reference to MyUtils and use some of it's classes.
   As it stands now, MyAgent may also need to access some types in MyUtils.

   Now, because of the fact that all types and members in MyUtils are internal, I am unable to add it as reference to MyConnector, and likewise from MyConnector to MyAgent. I do not want to make any of these types public because I do not want the application using my DLL to access them directly.

   I understand that theoretically it is possible to span a namespace over multiple assemblies, but not clear how to practically achieve the above scenario.
2. Finally I want to deploy just MyAgent.dll to be used in an EXE. That EXE should have access only to the public types in MyAgent, with one exception: a MyConnection object (type contained in MyConnector) would be returned from a MyAgent method. Here again, my access specifier (internal) restricts this possibility.

I've been overthinking this so much that I'm now completely confused. Would appreciate some guidance from experienced programmers very much.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a solution to your issue but I question the value of a utility assembly that has no public types. Can you describe more about why you want the utility types to remain internal?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. The last dll (MyAgent) has public types as well, and those are the ones the exe would call. But my need was to hide implementation details of all other assemblies that contain supporting implementation. Making those public would not only add unnecessary noise to the intellisese lists, but also enable and encourage the exe developers to toy around with what they shouldn't.

Comment: Anyway, I think I've found a way to achieve what I wanted, with a little compromise on how much should be public. So I'm considering this question resolved, and will ask a new one of i hit any new roadblocks. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spanning a namespace over multiple assemblies is done quite simple:

file1.cs in assembly 1:

```
namespace MyNamespace { ... }
```

file2.cs in assembly2:

```
namespace MyNamespace { ... }
```

However this won´t help you at all, as the `intenal` access-modifier will make your members visible to any class within the same *assembly*, regardless on their namespace. So even if you had two namespaces within assembly1, you could access all internal members declared in `assembly1.MyNamespace`, but not those within `assembly2.MyNamespace`.

So you *have* to make them `public` in order to access them from other assemblies. Alternativly you could also name a so-called "friend-assembly", that is able to access internal members from another assembly also. To do so, add an [`InternalsVisibleTo(fullNameForAssembly2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your code.

Comment: Oh, yes, internal is assembly scope! Is there no way to restrict scope to a namespace? I do not want users of my dll calling methods on my classes they are not supposed to. Edit: Will check out the alternative you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: See my last paragraph. The internalsvisibleto-attribute is what you´re looking for.

Comment: I thought I should let you know: Although I didn't use that attribute, I did learn something new from that link you posted, and it may come handy some time, so many thanks to you. In the mean time, I've kept it simpler and achieved almost what I wanted, with a little compromise on how much should be public. So I'm considering this question resolved, and will ask a new one of i hit any new roadblocks. Thanks for your time.